# In Incremental Learning will the model be updated automatically?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, machine-learning-model, online-learning

I came across [Incremental Learning algorithms](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224720096_Overview_of_Some_Incremental_Learning_Algorithms) paper, where incremental algorithms are compared. I have problem with general understanding. Will the model be updated /adapts itself automatically when new data comes in?

Does it know by itself that new  data has arrived and it learns?

In general, can anyone explain how training, testing, and model adaption is carried out with such incremental algorithms?

Comment: your link doesn't work (looks like a path to a local file)

Comment: @oW_ i have edited

Answer (score 1):

Incremental learning is analogous to **online learning**. It is based on the assumption that your model can receive a continuous stream of data from which it can keep learning indefinitely. Training is therefore based on **Mini-Batch Gradient Descent optimization**: you feed batches of data into the Network as soon an new data comes in.

Hope this helps, otherwise let me know.

Comment: not all online learning algorithms are based on mini-batch gradient descent, e.g. there are incremental versions of decision trees

Comment: Mini-Batch gradient descent is **mandatory** for online Deep Learning. Géron's book *Hands-On Machine Learning With Scikit-Learn and Tensorflow*, in my opinion the best book on ML ever written, said this too. Also, what you called *incremental versions of decision trees* must be based on feeding mini-batches of data into the model. Ok, certain model don't use gradient descent, but feeding mini-batches is mandatory for online / incremental learning.

Comment: Would the performance be the same as just retraining the whole model from scratch with the new data? Is this concept mainly used for speed purposes?